# Saving `RadioButton` state on Orientation change

Tags: android

1. My app has a `Fragment` attached to an `Activity`
   (which would ask yes or no questions to users.)
2. I have two `RadioButton` for each question
   (one for 'yes' and one for 'No'.)
3. Based on user's choice for each question the next question will be loaded.
   For example,

   `1. Are you at the accident scene?`
     `[  yes  ]  [  No  ]`

   - If the user answers 'yes' another question will be loaded.
   - If 'no' some other question will be loaded.

Now my problem is, when I change the **orientation** after the visibility of second question, only the first question appear(with `RadioButton` checked).

How to solve this? I ended here only after extensive google-ing. Please help.

Comment: what is your onclick or ontouch event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing a little more code it's hard to tell what the exact issue is but heres a good way to think of your issue:

When you rotate the device the activity saves its state and then restarts in the new orientation. `super.onSaveInstanceState();` and `super.onRestoreInstanceState();` take care of saving view states but they donot know about any other variables (like ones keeping track of what question the user was on).

Override onSave and onRestore to save / load your data during this transition.

Reading http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html should provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this. If it works for me i ll accept your answer as correct

Answer (score -2):

Hi please add like this in your manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".youractivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
```

your activity wont refresh if the user changes the **orientation**.

Comment: Sometimes you need `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` for this to work properly.

Comment: I need to refresh my activity.

Comment: @keerthanamurugesan what do you want exactly?

Comment: Worked for me when I added screen size, it is just a fix but not the exact solution to handle orientation.